# Java inject of final property

Tags: java, dependency-injection, final

Does @Inject cater for final fields?
That is once injected, cannot be changed.

I can't perform constructor injection because I need to use provider injection and prototype instantiation.

If not, any future plans for Java final syntax to be inject-aware?

Otherwise, when will Provider accept constructor arguments?

Comment: You'd get a compilation error way before any container had a chance to act.

Comment: According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html), members cannot be `final`.

Comment: use constructor arguments and do not annotate the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Guice for several injections besides contructor injection, for instance you also have method and field injection.

Furthermore, the constructor injection of Guice let's you set the dependencies on final properties.
Check out their page here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections